# GetResourceStream return Null for PDF WP8 (Window Phone 8 Emulator)

Tags: c#-4.0, pdf, windows-phone-8, pdf-generation

i am working on WP8 Emulator

```
var resource = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("testPath1.pdf", UriKind.Relative));
```

when i want to read pdf file return null value who to i get stream 
but i am using for images and txt  return stream

```
var resource = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

this line is working

Comment: check your .pdf file properties (in solution explorer, right-click -> properties) make sure it set up the same way as the .png file.

Comment: Yes sir the are same path even when i m using .txt file its open but when i want to open pdf file , get stream in resourse variable this code not working for pdf how i get stream for open pdf file in windows phone Please help me .......

Comment: what is **build action** property for both file (.pdf and .png)? *see my 1st comment if you don't know where to find **build action***